# Remotely run python script consisting of multiple files via ssh

Tags: ssh, python, remote

I want to run a python script remotely via ssh. For a single script this would be something like this:

```
ssh user@machine python test.py
```

If my python program consists of multiple files, I'm out of luck with this. As Python can execute zip-files, I created one and it runs perfectly on my local system:

```
python test.zip
```

Over ssh:

```
ssh user@machine python < test.zip
```

I got the error message "SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with...". Both files in the archive start with "-*- coding: utf-8 -*-".

What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: do you expect `test.zip` to be on the local machine or on the remote machine?

Comment: test.zip is on the local machine. I don't want to modify the remote machine by copying the .zip first but execute it directly.

Comment: I found this question on stackoverflow which is basically the same problem - but has no solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276105/why-cant-python-execute-a-zip-archive-passed-via-stdin

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem with

```
ssh user@machine python < test.zip
```

is that `test.zip` is sent to `ssh` instead of `python`.

The solution in [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276105/why-cant-python-execute-a-zip-archive-passed-via-stdin)  might work, if you'll implement the python-script mentioned there (copied below):

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import sys
import os
import zipfile
import StringIO
import zipimport
import time

sys.path.append('/tmp')

class SinEater(object):
    def __init__(self):
        tmp = str(int(time.time()*100)) + '.zip'
        f = open(tmp, 'w')
        f.write(sys.stdin.read(1024*64)) # 64kb limit
        f.close()
        try:
            z = zipimport.zipimporter(tmp)
            z.load_module('foo')

        except:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'herp derp'
    s = SinEater()
```

Save it as `zip_parse_script.py` **on the remote machine** and will execute your command using

```
test.zip | ssh user@machine python /path_to_python_script/zip_parse_script.py
```